# C++ function header matching: how does matching work when const and templates are both involved?

Tags: c++, templates, constants, shared-ptr

I had a templated function that I wished to call.  This is (a trimmed-down version of) the header:

```
template <typename Item>
void print (shared_ptr<const MyContainer<Item>> stuff, ostream& out)
```

which I tried to call with a line like this:

```
print (make_shared<MyContainer<int>>(42), cerr);
```

But the compiler complained that there was no match.  What confuses me is that the const mismatch is not a problem, because if I redeclare my function to omit the template it works:

```
void print (shared_ptr<const MyContainer<int>> stuff, ostream& out)  //matches!
```

On the other hand, if I omit constness, the templated version does work:

```
template <typename Item>
void print (shared_ptr<MyContainer<Item>> stuff, ostream& out)  //also matches!
```

But I *should* be able to write a function over const things and pass it a non-const value (which the function will then just not modify), right?  Indeed, if I go back to non-managed pointers, the corresponding old way to write the header would have been

```
template <typename Item>
void print (const MyContainer<Item>* stuff, ostream& out)
```

and indeed then a call to

```
print (new MyContainer<int>(42), cerr);  //yet another match!
```

once again just fine.

So, what is it about this particular cocktail of `shared_ptr`, templates, and `const` that causes the compiler to be unable to find the matching function?  (Running g++ 8.2.1, and clang++ 7.0.1 seems to produce the same result.)

Comment: Btw. I prefer `const shared_ptr<>&` parameters. This may safe an extra reference inc. which couldn't hurt.

Comment: The first part of your title "C++ function header matching:" is IMHO a bit mis-leading. My first impression was, you're assuming that the issue is caused by wrong include dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning const-ness of pointee, `std::shared_ptr` behaves a bit different than raw-pointers.

A `std::shared_ptr<T>` is not the same as a `std::shared_ptr<const T>`. It's even not that compatible to allow an implicit conversion. (The error message in [Daniels answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55625464/7478597) says this quite literally.)

It doesn't work for the same reason like in the following (counter) example:

```
template <typename T>
struct ContainerT {
  T a;
  ContainerT(T a): a(a) { }
  ContainerT(const ContainerT&) = default;
  ContainerT& operator=(const ContainerT&) = default;
};

int main()
{
  ContainerT<int> a(42);
  ContainerT<const int> b(a);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
g++ (GCC) 8.2.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:15:28: error: no matching function for call to 'ContainerT<const int>::ContainerT(ContainerT<int>&)'
   ContainerT<const int> b(a);
                            ^
main.cpp:8:3: note: candidate: 'constexpr ContainerT<T>::ContainerT(const ContainerT<T>&) [with T = const int]'
   ContainerT(const ContainerT&) = default;
   ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:8:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'ContainerT<int>' to 'const ContainerT<const int>&'
main.cpp:7:3: note: candidate: 'ContainerT<T>::ContainerT(T) [with T = const int]'
   ContainerT(T a): a(a) { }
   ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:7:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'ContainerT<int>' to 'int'
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9077ac6af7d51dab)</kbd>

---

In the case of `std::shared_ptr`, there is a way to circumvent this issue
→ a [`std::const_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) can be used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
struct ContainerT {
  T a;
  ContainerT(T a): a(a) { }
};

template <typename T>
void print(std::shared_ptr<const ContainerT<T>> ref, std::ostream &out)
{
  out << "print: '" << ref->a << "'\n";
}

int main()
{
  print(std::make_shared<const ContainerT<int>>(42), std::cout);
  print(std::const_pointer_cast<const ContainerT<int>>(std::make_shared<ContainerT<int>>(42)), std::cout);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
print: '42'
print: '42'
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85bbba0f09394290)</kbd>

---

For convenience, the const-cast might be done in another function template:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
struct ContainerT {
  T a;
  ContainerT(T a): a(a) { }
};

template <typename T>
void print(std::shared_ptr<const ContainerT<T>> ref, std::ostream &out)
{
  out << "print const: '" << ref->a << "'\n";
}

template <typename T>
void print(std::shared_ptr<ContainerT<T>> ref, std::ostream &out)
{
  out << "print non-const: ";
  print(std::const_pointer_cast<const ContainerT<T>>(ref), out);
}

int main()
{
  print(std::make_shared<const ContainerT<int>>(42), std::cout);
  print(std::make_shared<ContainerT<int>>(42), std::cout);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
print const: '42'
print non-const: print const: '42'
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6581a75643bb776)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified code:

```
template <typename T>
void f(std::shared_ptr<const std::vector<T>>) { }

void g(std::shared_ptr<const std::vector<int>>) { }

int main() {
  f(std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>()); // ERROR
  g(std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>()); // OK
}
```

To understand what happens, read the error message, e.g., the one printed by g++:

```
...
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   types 'const std::vector<T>' and 'std::vector<int>' have incompatible cv-qualifiers
```

It tells you that the problem is with template argument deduction/substitution. The C++ rules seemingly do not allow this type of deduction. (If I have some time, I will try to find a relevant part of the Standard).

---

However, you can skip the template argument deduction by providing an explicit template argument:

```
f<int>(std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>()); // OK
```

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<const T>` and `std::shared_ptr<T>` is unrelated except that there exists an implicit conversion between them. Templates have to be exact matches.